# Why have parenthesis become red in Visual Studio Code when writting TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

They used to be white as seen on https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript.

[image]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this is more of a ide settings issue.  You should be able to adjust the syntax colors to whatever you want them to be.  As for why it seemed to change, there could be a number of reasons.

Comment: @TonyAbrams Strange... I didn’t change anything at my end... perhaps a syntax color change (due to VSC update) or a bug?

Comment: Yeah, it's possible that an update or bug caused the change.

Comment: It’s amazing how such a simple thing can throw off productivity. Guess my brain is wired to efficiently make sense of these colors.

Comment: Check if you still have the correct theme applied in Settings ->Workbench->Appearance->Color Theme. Default is Default Dark+

Comment: Additionally, check your `settings.json` if the options `workbench.colorCustomizations` or `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` have been set for your user or your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Found the culprit. See https://github.com/material-theme/vsc-material-theme/issues/439#issuecomment-573343598

I use the [Material Theme](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Equinusocio.vsc-material-theme) theme. In a recent update, the color scheme I like has been renamed `Community Material Theme`.